# How to create javascript image gallery with slider picking images from a virtual directory...?

Tags: javascript

When the page loads, it creates a list of image files hosted in a virtual directory, and the first image is loaded in the image box.

Currently, I am picking images from the same folder.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
  <img class="demo cursor" src="img1.jpg" style="width:100%;height:40px" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="IMAGE# 1">
</div>
<div class="column">
  <img class="demo cursor" src="img2.jpg" style="width:100%;height:40px" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="IMAGE# 2">
</div>
<div class="column">
  <img class="demo cursor" src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%;height:40px" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="IMAGE# 3">
</div>
```